# Convert PHP array to new data-structure

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I have a MYSQL query which returns the following PHP array `$result`:

[image: visual table]

```
[0] => Array (
    [resourceKey] => cloth
    [date] => 2020-09-06
    [quantity] => 8
    )
[1] => Array (
    [resourceKey] => ebony
    [date] => 2020-09-06
    [quantity] => 4
    )
[2] => Array (
    [resourceKey] => gems
    [date] => 2020-09-06
    [quantity] => 0
    )
[3] => Array (
    [resourceKey] => lead
    [date] => 2020-09-06
    [quantity] => 0
    )
[4] => Array (
    [resourceKey] => limestone
    [date] => 2020-09-06
    [quantity] => 8
    )
[5] => Array (
    [resourceKey] => cloth
    [date] => 2020-09-05
    [quantity] => 6
    )
[6] => Array (
    [resourceKey] => ebony
    [date] => 2020-09-05
    [quantity] => 3
    )
[7] => Array (
    [resourceKey] => gems
    [date] => 2020-09-05
    [quantity] => 0
    )
[8] => Array (
    [resourceKey] => lead
    [date] => 2020-09-05
    [quantity] => 0
    )
[9] => Array (
    [resourceKey] => limestone
    [date] => 2020-09-05
    [quantity] => 6
    )
```

And I need to convert it is a certain way to display it with jquery Datatables:

```
$data= array(
    array("Date" => "2020-09-05","cloth"=>"6","ebony"=>"3","gems"=>"0","lead"=>"0","limestone"=>"6"),
    array("Date" => "2020-09-06","cloth"=>"8","ebony"=>"4","gems"=>"0","lead"=>"0","limestone"=>"8")
);
```

I've been trying for a while now but can't get a good way to iterate through the results...

I have already taken care of building the columns to pass to Datatables:

```
$columns = array();
$columns[] = array('data' => 'Date', 'title' => 'Date');
foreach ($result as $key => $row_data) {
    $newResourceKey = $myUtilities->in_array_recursive($row_data['resourceKey'], $columns);
        
    if ($newResourceKey === FALSE) {    // Only if column name not yet in array
        $columns[] = array('data' => $row_data['resourceKey'], 'title' => $row_data['resourceKey']);
    }
        
}
```

This is an example of the many things I've tried:

```
$isDateInArray = $myUtilities->in_array_recursive($row_data['date'], $data);
if ($isDateInArray === FALSE) { // Only if Date is not in array yet
    array_push($data, array('Date' => $row_data['date'], $row_data['resourceKey'] => $row_data['quantity']));   // Push date and data
}
else {
    array_push($data, array($row_data['resourceKey'] => $row_data['quantity']));    // Only push data. Can't find a way to add it to existing Date array
}
```

Update:

```
public function in_array_recursive($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && $this->in_array_recursive($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What about json?

Comment: Php to json is not my problem. It is the way the PHP array is structured, it needs to be organized in a different way. All the resourceKeys for a specific date need to be in the same entry

Comment: What's in `$myUtilities->in_array_recursive` Method? Sounds like you just need to loop the data & build a new data-structure with it, then save

Comment: You are right @admcfajn I need to build a new data-structure (similar to my example `$data`) but I don't manage to do that. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result by next simple array transformation:

```
$res = [];
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $res[$row['date']][$row['resourceKey']] = $row['quantity'];
}

$final = [];

foreach ($res as $d=>$r) {
    array_push($final, array_merge(['date'=>$d], $r));
}
print_r($final);
```

[Here you can try the PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=3f91e2ad1b79eb7805bf9902cd0283fe&sqlses=4fe6c1c3a0de41c8592ea80961838775&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Perfect thanks! The `array_merge` did the trick and your code produces the expected result